# How do I find the time difference between two timestamps?

Tags: php, timestamp, difference

Let's say I have two mongo dates.

```
$a = $mongoDateA->sec;
$b = $mongoDateB->sec;
```

So now I have two timestamps to compare, but I need to figure out, if dateB is any later than a day more than dateA.

so if the difference between the two dates is 1 day, I need to perform another tasks, but I have no idea how to get the difference?

How do I tackle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`DateTimeInterval`](http://php.net/manual/class.dateinterval.php)

```
$dtA = new DateTime();
$dtA->setTimestamp($a);

$dtB = new DateTime();
$dtB->setTimestamp($b);

$diff = $dtA->diff($dtB);
if ($diff->days >= 1) {
    // perform other tasks
}
```

Answer (score 0):

They are unix timestamp, the unit is second, so just:

```
if ($b - $a > 86400) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: What about DST boundaries?